# Inserting Multiple Inherited Entities Gives - Unable to determine the principal end of the relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using EF5 and I'm having an issue where I can add 1 instance of an inherited entity and save it successfully, but if I add two or more instances of the type, I run into the issue below.

These entities are inherited types from a base type.  FkEssayItemContent is the FK relationship that ties my type, `EssayItem`, to it's base, `Content`.

```
Unable to determine the principal end of the 
'TDSModel.FkEssayItemContent' relationship. 
Multiple added entities may have the same primary key.
```

What am I missing here, such that one entity would insert fine, but two of them inserted at once would cause this problem when using inheritance?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up answering this myself.  It turns out that in addition to an inheritance relationship, the model had an association between `EssayItem` and `Content'.  Removing that association and maintaining the inheritance fixed the issue.